# ireport is not decoding utf-8 bin data of mysql

Tags: java, mysql, jasper-reports, ireport

I am using iReport 4.5.1. I have created a report which is fetching data from a mysql database.

My database has some fields which are storing Gujarati Language fonts with collation: utf 8 bin.

Within database these data looks like this:

`&#2744&#271&#2750`

Which is encoding for:

`&#2744;&#2741;&#2750;&#2736;-&#2732;&#2730;&#2763;&#2736;-&#2744;&#2750;&#2690;&#2716;`

I have installed Gujarati fonts (called `Shruti` fonts) in the iReport.

Now I am trying to show these fields with Gujarati Language Fonts (Shruti fonts). But it's not working. It's showing same encoded data like this:

```
&#2744&#271&#2750...
```

What should I do, in order for iReport to decode that data?

---

Another scenario is when I am passing Gujarati fonts as parameter (By typing in Gujarati text, not encoded) then it's working on ireport side:

[image: Image 1]

But not working when I pass gujarati fonts from my application side:

[image: Image 2]